# Xamarin UI Test [Navigation]

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uitest

I would like to ask a question regarding UI Test when continuously navigation from one page to another and so on. If I launch a UI Test, do I need to continuously navigate from one page to another for one specific test or can it be chopped into pieces without launching the app again and again? Thanks

e.g.

```
[Test]
public void Navigation()
{
    app.Tap("button1NavigateToPage1");
    app.WaitForElement("ElementInPage1"); //If Success
    app.Tap("buttonNavigateToPage2");
    app.Tap("buttonNavigateToPage3");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test should start from normal state. That is why the app is relaunched every test.

It shouldn't take a lot of time and you don't have to watch it doing the things it does.

It will show you a summary in the end of failed tests and you can rerun those and check them again.

You can also take a screenshot to make sure that the flow went as intended

```
app.Screenshot("First screen.");
```

Comment: I see. I thought it can be launched differently. Thanks